# ResultSet to CachedRowSet

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, jdbi, cachedrowset

I'm trying to convert from `ResultSet` to `CachedRowSet/CachedRowSetImpl`. The `ResultSet` seems to be empty after the populate method, but so does the `CachedRowSet`. I have been searching all over the place, trying different approaches (including Factory). Below is a code snippet with some indications of what is going on.

```
class ResultSetMapper implements RowMapper<CachedRowSet>{
    @Override
    public CachedRowSet map(ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
        //CachedRowSet crs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet(); 
        System.out.println(rs.getLong("something")); -> This gets printed
        CachedRowSetImpl crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        crs.populate(rs);
        System.out.println(crs.getInt("something"); -> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (mostly -1, sometimes returning 0)
        System.out.println(rs.getLong("something")); -> This doesn't get printed
        System.out.println(crs.size()); -> 0
        return crs;
    }
}
```

Any help or insight to this problem will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Through some debugging, I found that the CachedRowSet is **not empty**. The RowSetMD.colCount = 3. It also has the right labels. This doesn't change the issue, but assures that I'm not calling getters on an empty object. This makes the issue even harder to grasp

Comment: If you are using `Spring-JDBC`, try adding that as a tag.

Answer (score 1):

The `CachedRowSet::populate` method reads all rows from your `ResultSet`. At that point it is no longer possible to call `rs.next()`. You should use `csr.next()`.

```
class ResultSetMapper implements RowMapper<CachedRowSet>{
    @Override
    public CachedRowSet map(ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
        CachedRowSet crs = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();
        crs.populate(rs);
        while (csr.next()) {
            System.out.println(crs.getInt("something"));
        }
        // ...
        return null;
    }
}
```